# Can hard coded and self-sizing table cells be intermixed within a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm working on an app that will populate the tableview based on a web service response.  So far the two content types I know I will be getting will be data shown in a textview, and also in a collection view.  I've begun implementing Ash Furrow's [AFCollectionView](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/).  The dynamic sizing for text areas is working, however the collection view is scrolling within a cell height that is even less than my estimatedRowHeight (210.0).

Because the collection view table cell is not correctly resizing is it possible to explicitly set the height for the collectionView cell(s), and let any of the text based cells remain dynamic?

### [image: Table when first loaded]

[image: Table with collection view partially scrolled.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your self sizing cells use auto-layout to determine what height to be, and that's based on the intrinsic content size of the subviews. But, that's not the only way auto-layout can specify the height of a view. You can add a static height constraint to your cells which contain a collection view.